# python 3.x - Gmail api get title and sender

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I have just started working with the Gmail API and have followed the Oauth2.0 tutorial to get the autherisation code. my code so far is:

```
from oauth2client import client
import webbrowser
import httplib2

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
    'client_secrets.json',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
webbrowser.open_new(auth_uri)

authcode = input("Enter auth code: ")

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(authcode)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

I would like to test the API by making a request which gets the subject and  sender of the latest unread message in this kind of format:

```
#pseudocode
get latestMessage
if latestMessage.read == True:
    print("you have no unread messages)
else:
    print("you have a new email: " + latestMessage.subject + " from" + latestmessage.sender)
```

Comment: Titles and senders are burried quite deep. Use messages.get() first to get the message, then it's under payload -> headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991551/5832311), if you want headers like To, From, Subject then you can call [`messages.get(format=METADATA)`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) or however it looks in the language you're using. You may check the [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages) in the documentation.

```
Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """

  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

You may also check the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781501/get-sender-email-from-gmail-api) on how to get the sender of the email.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pushed me in the right direction to get this to work, although I think you may have meant to link [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) instead :)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a template script (Python 3.5) to access Gmail and get params such as date, subject, snippet, sender email, and message body.

You can check it on my github repository, and fork if you wish. The link is https://github.com/abhishekchhibber/Gmail-Api-through-Python.

Comment: Thanks for this, others may find this useful when looking at this thread. I will also check through to see if the efficiancy of what i've done can be improved!